# How to change a python path in sudo state?

Tags: python, bash, sudo, pythonpath

My problem is that when I do :

$ which python 
=> I get /a/b/c/python as my directory

but if I do 
$ sudo which python
=> I get /d/e/python as the result

How do I change the sudo one to match with the normal case, it is making it impossible to install libraries from source.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://askubuntu.com/questions/477987/two-python-distributions-sudo-picking-the-wrong-one this is a result of secure_path (specified in /etc/sudoers) overriding your normal PATH.

I've worked around it by giving the path to the path to the binary I want to run. For example:

```
$ which pip
/opt/local/bin/pip
$ sudo /opt/local/bin/pip install foo
```

It's not ideal but it works and doesn't subvert secure_path.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the first one found in $PATH

try doing

`echo $PATH`

then

`sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'`

I bet these are different.

In any case, there is usually an rc script of some sort for the shell you use in both /root and your current user, just rearrange the paths in the environment variable for the one you want.

Comment: I am getting both the paths to be the same.

Comment: @Kakashi: that's because str8 gave you the wrong command: `sudo echo $PATH` will substitute in the path before invoking `sudo`, so doesn't tell you anything. (S)he meant to write something like `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'`, which prints out the path seen by a command that `sudo` runs. If you run that, you'll see that `sudo` runs with a path that includes `/usr/bin` before `/usr/local/bin`, or (more likely) doesn't include `/usr/local/bin` at all.

Comment: `sudo echo $PATH` will expand YOUR path, and pass it to sudo to echo as root!

Answer (score 0):

I would first try this:

```
sudo -i which python
```

which (indirectly) causes the `root` user's profile to be run, including any non-default configuration of the path. (By default, `sudo` doesn't bother with that.)

If that doesn't work, then that tells you that `/usr/local/bin` isn't in the path set up by the `root` user's profile (or isn't before `/usr/bin`), so your options are either to change the `root` user's profile and use the above, or else to use:

```
sudo -E which python
```

to preserve *your* path (and the rest of your environment). This may be less secure.

For full details on each of these options, see [the `sudo` man-page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html).